# Can we add custom hidden fields to the mailbox item in outlook add-in?

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

In compose mode of Meet/Mail can we add some **custom hidden fields** to mailbox item in outlook add-in code which is persisted in the mailbox when send, so when in the Edit/View of the created item we can read those custom fields to perform some operation in outlook add-in code.

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify what your specific scenario is?

However, it is likely the Internet Headers interface is what you want to use to set on the compose mail:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.internetheaders?view=outlook-js-preview

And Read them on the Read Mail:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.messageread?view=outlook-js-preview#getAllInternetHeadersAsync_options__callback_

If you are only interested in setting values on the Compose Item, and reading them in the Sent Item folder, then Custom Properties could also work:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.customproperties?view=outlook-js-preview

(But these are NOT Transmittable, so the receiver of the email will not get them)

Comment: Outlook Add-ins Team - MSFT , I want some fields to be persisted, like when we create a meet I have created a third party meet id I want that to be saved somewhere hidden so that it can be used when the user modifies the meet I can use the meet id to call modify to the third party meet.

Comment: Custom Properties would probably do what you want. (but note that Custom Properties do not propagate to the Instances of Recurring Items) If this is required, you may need to make an ews call via MakeEWSRequestAsync, to get the properties of the parent item.